# Override private function in Leaflet.Draw

Tags: leaflet.draw

I have added two Leaflet.Draw plugins to my application where one of them is used for pure drawing and the other one im just using to get the drawn polygon to use for some spatial querying.

I need to have both of them but when **draw:created** is fired, both of the tools will capture the event.

I wonder if my approach to "override" a private function is bad practice and if there is any better way to accomplish it.

My approach is to extend L.Draw.Feature and change the function **_fireCreateEvent** to send a custom event:

```
_fireCreatedEvent: function (layer) {
    //send custom event 
},
```